# Emacs major mode key map definition fails

Tags: emacs, elisp

So, I've tried to write a simple major mode (report-mode) [using](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/elisp-manual-21-2.8/html_node/elisp_350.html) as an example.  I seem to have everything working except that the keymap doesn't actually seem to map.

If I do `C-h f report-mode` I correctly see a list of key maps with the addition I did, namely:

```
ESC  n    kill-dupe
```

However, when I go to USE M-n or ESC n, nothing happens.  I can manually invoke the function via `M-x kill-dupe` so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Sadly, because the machine is on a different network, I can't copy-paste the actual elisp code.

I can copy in the exact example I used (and make the substitions):

```
(defvar report-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap "Report-Mode")))
    (define-key map "\M-n" 'kill-dupe)
    map)
 "Keymap for browsing report mode")
```

which comes from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Example-Major-Modes.html).

If I examine report-mode-map, I see what looks mostly correct, except it has additional keywords of `keymap` within:

```
(keymap (27 keymap (110 . kill-dupe)) keymap (....) "Report-Map" (....))
```

If I compare this with, say, text-mode-map, it has the sparse-key-map definition string embedded, and additional 'keymap' strings.  If I eval `(keymapp report-mode-map)` I get a result of true, so that would seem to indicate the different format isn't a problem ...

Lastly, I'm pretty sure it IS a problem, because none of the other keymap bindings work either.

Any ideas would be great.  Sorry again for not being able to past the code directly.

Comment: Are you sure your major mode is called `report-mode`  -- if not, it won't work out of the box?  `(define-derived-mode . . .`.

Comment: okay, thanks - I didn't include the `(define-derived-mode report-mode text-mode ... )` call.  I do have that.

Comment: What I meant to type was " I didn't include in the question definition" I do have define-derived-mode in the report-mode.el file.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found the answer.

Turns out I in `define-derived-mode` I never invoked `use-local-map` on my custom key map.

once I included:

`(use-local-map report-mode-map)`

Everything worked fine.